# Sencha Architect -- Deploying

Tags: android, ios, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Is Sencha Architect required to package, deploy, etc. an app for Android/ioS, and for the app store/Google play? The below doc seems to imply that Architect is really important for deployment (the package button):

http://docs.sencha.com/architect/2/#!/guide/deploy

(

Answer (score 1):

No actually! Sencha Architect is a tool that simplifies your work and makes you write less code. You can use Sencha CMD to package, deploy or simulate your Sencha application. Basically, this works on your command prompt/terminal and a few commands will acheive the desired result. Follow the below links which are helpful:

http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/3.1.2/#!/guide/command_reference

http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/3.1.2/#!/guide/native_packaging

http://www.sencha.com/learn/sencha-touch-2-native-packaging-demos

http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/3.1.2/#!/guide/command_app_touch

Best Luck!

Comment: An alternative that is worth mentioning is to wrap your sencha app in a PhoneGap project then follow these tutorials for native deployment on each platform http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides